# Search the last modified ".mxd" files in directory and sub-directory- Python Error

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system, directory, subdirectory, last-modified

I try to find the last modified files which end with ".mxd" in directory and sub-directory and print the modified time, using this code:

```
import os

max_mtime = 0
for dirname,subdirs,files in os.walk(r"G:\desktop\Project"):
    for fname in files:
        if fname.endswith(".mxd"):
            full_path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
            mtime = os.stat(full_path).st_mtime
            if mtime > max_mtime:
                max_mtime = mtime
                max_dir = dirname
                max_file = fname
                print os.path.getatime(fname)

print max_dir, max_file
```

but when i run this code it raise an error and i don't understand what is my mistake:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] : 'project.mxd'
```

I red [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) but didn't found any way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly, this code worked for well:

```
import os,time,datetime,glob

path = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for dirname,subdirs,files in os.walk(path):
    max_mtime = 0
    max_dir = ""
    max_file =""
    for fname in files:
        mtime=0
        if fname.endswith(".mxd"):
            full_path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
            mtime = os.stat(full_path).st_mtime
            if mtime > max_mtime:
                max_mtime = mtime
                max_dir = dirname
                max_file = fname
    print max_dir, max_file
    print
```